# live stream in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

is it possible to show TV channel lively through streaming ? any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS supports live streaming in native apps and in Safari. [Apple have an overview document here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).